# How can i access my dockerised flask application from a separate device on the host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-network

I've created a API on a flask application that i'm trying to access from my phone on the same network as the windows host machine but i'm having no luck.

I'm running docker desktop on windows 10 with a WSL 2 (ubuntu) backend which is enabled. I can access the API if run the script outside of the docker container from my phone but not when it is running in the container. I can also access the API from the windows device by going to localhost:port/endpoint or hostip:port:endoint but i cannot access it using the windows host ip from a device on the same ip range.

I'm aware they is a different network for the docker container and WSL backend:

- home network - 192.168.0.X
- WSL 2  -  172.27.145.194
- Flask container - 172.18.0.2

This is my docker-compose:

```
tfmodelserving:
  build: ./tfserving/docker-image
  container_name: tfserving
  ports:
    - "5001:5001"
  volumes:
    - ./tfserving/drive/src:/src
```

and the dockerfile for it:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.10.0-gpu

COPY ./packages/ /packages
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libjack-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev libsndfile1 -y \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt
CMD python3 packages/speech_to_text/stt_api.py
EXPOSE 5001
```

It doesnt seem to be very clear what further configuration i need to do here. From what i've read they seems to be alot of suggestion that just publishing the ports should do the trick. I've also read about macvlan being a option but seems to be only supported on a linux host.

My networking knowledge is fairly limited but it seems quite complicated to configure this docker container to be accessible from my home network. I feel like i need to find a way to link the docker network to the home network but i am unsure on the best approach to doing this.

This is my first post so i apologise if things are not explained very clearly.If someone could nudge me in the direction of how this could be done it would be great!

Comment: You should be able to reach it on port 5001 on the IP address of the Windows machine.

Comment: That was my thought but it just hangs when i go to the ip:port from a different device

Comment: If you can reach it on the Windows machine using `localhost:5001`, it might be the Windows firewall blocking the traffic.

Comment: yeah i thought that could be the case but the fact i can reach it from my phone if the flask script is ran outside the container makes me think its to do with docker networking